# How to have a `Service` run on BOOT_COMPLETED in api 26?

Tags: android, service

I've really tried, but couldn't find anything on it. I have a `Service` (not `IntentService`) that stays in the background constantly calling a web service to see if there's any updates regarding a user, and if there is, shows a notification.

This service must start on `BOOT_COMPELETED`, but new limitations in api 26 has made it hard.

So how can I bypass these limitations, and use my service?

I could check if api >= 26, start the service as `foreground` and then immediately bind a notification with `IMPORTANCE_MIN` to it so it wouldn't be shut down and would work correctly, but I'd prefer not cluttering user's notification fold(!). So any other ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run continuously in the background, you must use a foreground service.

The correct way of doing this is:

1. Have your web service push updates to devices instead of constantly polling
2. Use an API like [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) to periodically poll your web service (this is limited to at most every 15 minutes)

Comment: Seems like the `WorkManager` is the only way forward. Here's a nice read for anyone interested: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/services-the-life-with-without-and-worker-6933111d62a6